# Creating generic classes and functions in javascript ES06

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm from java background. I use Generics in java in following way:

```
  class ApiResponse<T> {

    T data;

    T getData(){
      return T;
    }
  }
```

I'm unable to use generics in javascript ES06. I wanna know whether it's possible or not creating generic classes?

Comment: such syntax does not exist in javascript - so - no (since javascript isn't strictly typed, it would make little sense) (try "typescript" if you wnat strictly typed javascript) https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html ... or haxe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript in itself doesn't provide any syntax to support generic classes. But it's possible using:

> Flow

or

> Typescript

Let me show an example of using generic class using Flow in javascript ES06:

```
export class ApiResponse<T> {

    data: ?T = null
}
```

Answer (score 9):

JavaScript is a dynamically typed language and it doesn't have any generics. You can write a normal function/method, it will work for all types.

P.S. Use Typescript if want to code like you do in Java.

Comment: Currently I'm using "Flow" for type-checking. Can I use TypeScript with Flow?

Comment: @RahulRastogi I don't think so. I have not used Flow but I think both are competitors, You use one or another. Try https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/

Answer (score 9):

How do you like this, Elon Musk? Pure js, no typeflow/typescript

```
class BaseClass {
    hello = function () {
        console.log('hello!');
    }
}

function GenericClass(T, Base) {
    return class extends Base {
        field = new T();
    }
}

class DerivedFromGeneric extends GenericClass(String, BaseClass) {
    greet = function() {
        this.hello();
        console.log('greetings ', this.field);
    }
}

let i = new DerivedFromGeneric();
```

Comment: I like this! Why not?

Comment: It's not working when field is an Array<T>.

Comment: not sure where did you find Array<T> in JS, because that is syntax of typescript. class DerivedFromGeneric extends GenericClass(Array, BaseClass)  works

Answer (score 2):

Javascript doesn't have strict typing so there is no need for Generics because all variables can be assigned to any type at any time.

Comment: I've type-checking support using "Flow".

Answer (score 2):

You can use Typescript for this purpose.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html