# Simplifying an Addition/Subtraction Function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, math, abstraction

I've been asked to turn these two JavaScript functions into a generic function, but I am honestly not sure how to do this:

```
const increase = (_from, _by, _min) => Math.max(_from * _by, _from + _min);
const decrease = (_from, _by, _min) => Math.min(_from / _by, _from - _min);
```

I understand that if instead of a value greater than `1`, for example `.25`, the multiplication operator can remain, but I still use `Math.max()`/`Math.min()`.
So is there a way to make this more generic, without having to add an additional parameter?

Comment: it's not clear, what allows you to determine whether to use one or the other of your functions?

Comment: perhaps you did not understand the assignment. Generic Function has a particular meaning. In a nutshell, type of the function parameters is also a parameter in a call so that logic could be applicable to different types.

Comment: In addition to Mister Jojo's comment in my opinion already each function's wording/naming is misleading. What was the name of the unified generic functionality.

Comment: Can this shine any light? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47278140/creating-generic-classes-and-functions-in-javascript-es06/47278191